# Core Data delete issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the following code to delete a record from Core Data:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

            let recordToDelete = varUserClients[indexPath.row]

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

            managedContext.deleteObject(recordToDelete)

                do {
                    try managedContext.save()

                } catch let error as NSError  {

                    NSLog("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            clientsTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

            clientsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

The code successfully deletes the record, but it also crashes the app.  Everything else works fine.  What am I doing wrong here?

PS:  This is the error message I'm getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

**PPS:  As requested by @GeneratorOfOne, here's the rest of the code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return varUserClients.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let IndividualCell = clientsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CUSTOMCLIENTS

        let client = varUserClients[indexPath.row]

        let varFirstName = client.valueForKey("clientsFirstName") as! String
        let varLastName = client.valueForKey("clientsLastName") as! String
        let varFullName = String("\(varFirstName) \(varLastName)")

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_UserClientFullName.text = varFullName

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_UserClientPhoneNumber.text = (client.valueForKey("clientsMobilePhoneNumber") as! String)

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_UserClientEmailAddress.text = (client.valueForKey("clientsWorkEmailAddress") as! String)

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_UserClientPosition.text = (client.valueForKey("clientsJobTitle") as! String)

        IndividualCell.outletLabel_UserClientDistributionList.text = (client.valueForKey("clientsDistributionList") as! String)

        let varSelectPriorityPic = client.valueForKey("clientsDistributionList") as! String
        switch varSelectPriorityPic {
        case constRiskMatrixCodeLevel01:
            IndividualCell.outletImage_UserClientDistributionListImage.image = UIImage(named: "clientpriority1")
        case constRiskMatrixCodeLevel02:
            IndividualCell.outletImage_UserClientDistributionListImage.image = UIImage(named: "clientpriority2")
        case constRiskMatrixCodeLevel03:
            IndividualCell.outletImage_UserClientDistributionListImage.image = UIImage(named: "clientpriority3")
        case constRiskMatrixCodeLevel04:
            IndividualCell.outletImage_UserClientDistributionListImage.image = UIImage(named: "clientpriority4")
        case constRiskMatrixCodeLevel05:
            IndividualCell.outletImage_UserClientDistributionListImage.image = UIImage(named: "clientpriority5")
        default:
            break
        }
        return IndividualCell
    }
```

Comment: Show your implementation for cellForRowAtIndexPath: and numberOfRowsInSection: method, then it makes it easier to evaluate your scenario.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne - Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also delete the item from the data source array.

I recommend the order to delete first the item from the data source (model) and the table view (view) then delete the item in Core Data.

Important note: `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` reorders the table automatically. You must not call `reloadData()`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        let recordToDelete = varUserClients[indexPath.row]
        varUserClients.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        clientsTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        managedContext.deleteObject(recordToDelete)
        do {
           try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError  {
           NSLog("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks, @vadian, I understand what you're saying and it makes perfect sense.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSFetchedResultsController` and their delegate protocol methods. And then you can easily manage your tableView. If you want to delete, update or insert objects on the UITableView in Core Data!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        let recordToDelete = varUserClients[indexPath.row]

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        managedContext.deleteObject(recordToDelete)

            do {
                try managedContext.save()

            } catch let error as NSError  {

                NSLog("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

       // clientsTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
       // This is should be works! Try this out

        clientsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```